# react-router match query string

Tags: reactjs, match, react-router

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/example

I tried the example on `npm start`

query string match to route is not working on the example.
When I click the second one, It's activating wrong one

http://localhost:8080/query-params/user/bob?showAge=1
and refreshing on the link above not matching any routes.

Even if I have change the example code to below

      `<Route path="user/:userID(?:showAge)" component={User} />`

I tried couple of things that might work based on docs but none of them worked.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out there was error on the example on react-router github.

I've made a PR for it which removes `activeClassName` for Link component.

without it, it works fine, and query string is in location props, see below

```
this.props.location.query = { 
  query1: value1,
  query2: value2
}
```

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7f2k.png)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the root (`/`) in `path="user/:userID(?:showAge)"`

This code must works:

```html
 <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/user/:userID/:showAge)" component={User} />
 </Router>
```

Check if the params are in the route:

```js
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.routeParams));
```

> [My whole file](https://github.com/aarkerio/vet4pet/blob/master/app/assets/frontend/javascripts/entry.js)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's not about query string.