# query string react-router path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I am using react-router 3.0.2 and trying to configure router path with query string. This is how I have configured my router:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="abc/login.do" component={LoginComponent}/>
                <Route path="abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=def" component={VerifyComponent} />
                <Route path="abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=ghi" component={ImageComponent}/>
                <Route path="*" component={LoginComponent}/>
</Router>
```

I understand this is not the right way to specify query string (?) in "Route". How do I make sure that whenever a user enters "http://localhost:3000/abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=def" in the url, "VerifyComponent" shows up, and when he enters "http://localhost:3000/abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=ghi" in the url, "ImageComponent" shows up.

I did check some cases here: [react-router match query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094765/react-router-match-query-string) and [Querystring in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109590/querystring-in-react-router), but unable to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You can write a wrapper component, that will switch what to render based on the query parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a wrapper component, that will switch what to render based on the query parameter

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="abc/login.do" component={LoginComponent}/>
   <Route path="abc/publicLoginID.do" component={WrapperComponent} />
   <Route path="*" component={LoginComponent}/>
</Router>

//WrapperComponent

WrapperComponent = (props) => {
   if (props.location.query.phase==="def"){return <VerifyComponent {...props}/>}
   if (props.location.query.phase==="ghi"){return <ImageComponent {...props}/>}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @UG_, it worked. My only concern is, if we have a router like this

`<Router history={browserHistory}>
         <Route path="abc/login.do?phase=jkl" component={RandomComponent}/>
<Route path="abc/login.do?phase=mno" component={LoginComponent}/>
           <Route path="abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=def" component={VerifyComponent} />
            <Route path="abc/publicLoginID.do?phase=ghi" component={ImageComponent}/>
                <Route path="*" component={LoginComponent}/>
</Router>`

Will we need 2 wrapper components, one for login.do and another for publicLoginID.do ?

Comment: yes, ideally I would want to handle two routes separately.

Comment: You can also put all of it in one component and switch based on routes, but that defeats the purpose of using react-router