# react-router - show component by parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question regarding `react-router` (v4).
Is it possible to show specific components by url parameter?

The url `/` shows the standard page, but if I provide a parameter in the url (i.e. `/?target=privacy`), then I want to show the `Privacy` component instead.

Actually my routes look like this:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={MainPage} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123743/query-string-react-router-path

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try this.

Comment: That's it! That solved my problem! Thank you so much!